GCP Cloud Build failed 401 Unauthorized even when Artifact Registry Administrator is granted
I'm trying to use GCP Cloud Build to automate my deployment, but I'm getting 401 error when it tries to pull dependency from Artifact Registry:
Could not GET 'https://europe-west1-maven.pkg.dev/myapp-456k4/jars/com/ai/common/0.0.0/common-0.0.0.pom'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized

The service account associated with this trigger has already been granted Artifact Registry Administrator role. In fact, this same account was able to push the common-0.0.0 artifact to the registry.
It can also pull the artifacts on my local machine as well, using this env variable:
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=~/Projects/Backend/creds/gcloud/myapp-456k4-automation-84958kdu9d845.json

What am I missing here?
Thanks
Update
It's because I'm using Docker to build the image instead of running gradle directly, so the service account credential is not passed to the Docker step.
So the question now is how to pass the credential to the gradle step of Docker build.
Update 2
I was able to resolve this by saving the credential json on Secret Manager, then retrieve it during the build, save it to a file, pass it the Docker build as a secret and use it to set env GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS

Can you try giving Artifact Registry Repository Administrator role? Also check the troubleshooting steps given in this thread. Can you share what is the exact error you are getting?

I tried a bit more and found that it's because the creds doesn't get passed to the Docker step.

Can you share the code that access your registry?

Thank you guys for chiming in, I was able to resolve this. You guys can check the update to see how I did it

If your issue is resolved? Can you provide the resolution steps you have followed and provide it as an answer for the greater visibility of the community.

I did in the Update 2
